# lit-element update individual child properties efficently

Tags: lit-element

I have the following components

`my-app`: contains a `layout-toolbar` and a `layout-container`

`layout-container`: contains one or more `layout-pages`

`layout-page`: contains one or more `layout-elements`

`layout-element`: component to visualize certain data, f.e. a styled numeric label.

The layout-container has an `options` property that is bound to the apps `layoutContainerOptions` property like this:

```
<layout-container .options="${this.layoutContainerOptions}"></layout-container>
```

`layoutContainerOptions` is initialized like this:

```
this.layoutContainerOptions = {
    name: "Project 1",
    pages: [
        {
            name: "Page 1",
            elements: [
                {
                    name: "Element 1",
                    color: "red"
                },
                {
                    name: "Element 2",
                    color: "yellow"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Page 2",
            elements: [
            ...
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This correctly renders a layout with two pages and some elements. Now the user should be able to use the toolbar to interactively edit selected elements, f.e. to change the color of an element. How do I propagate a property change to a selected child element?

I could use something like

```
this.layoutContainerOptions.pages[0].elements[0].color = "blue";        
this.layoutContainerOptions = Object.assign({}, layoutContainerOptions, { });
```

This works but seems to be very inefficient because there may be hundreds of elements which all get re-rendered (or don't they?)

What is the most efficient way to update properties of individual child elements?

Comment: As far as I know, lit-html is very efficient in terms of detecting whether the values in the templates actually changed so you might not need to do much, you could probably test this in Chrome dev tools or so on, open the "Elements" inspector tab and trigger an update, all the nodes that get updated will blink there

Comment: Good tip with the dev tools. Using the Object.assign hack the changes propagate but I see only the actually changed element blink, which is good! The processor load stays low too, even with over 100 elements in the layout page. Still it feels a little like a hack to have to use Object.assign to convince lit-element that something changed. Polymer has the set method that allows me to do something like this this.set('profile.name', 'Alex'); which is much more intuitive to me. But I haven't found something like this in lit-element.